# Unity | Can a GameObject know its position within a grid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a simple card game in Unity where the cards are placed on a 3x3 grid. I've created a prefab called CardSlot, and have written a script to instantiate a CardSlot for each of the 9 places.

The Board object on which the CardSlots are arranged has a Grid Layout component, which is how they are positioned when they are instantiated.

The game relies on placing cards into card slots and then interacting with adjacent cards. This means that at the point that a card is dropped onto a card slot, I need to know which slots are adjacent to the one that has just received a card.

So my question is, is there an easy way to know where in the grid a CardSlot is, and therefore which slots are adjacent?

Thanks

Comment: `GameObject.transform.position` is your friend.  Just modulus it to your grid size.

Comment: `is there an easy way to know where in the grid a CardSlot is` .. why don't you simply tell your slots what grid position they have when you instantiate them? You could also already let them store the adjacent slots so you don't even have to figure that out every time over and over again...

Comment: @MickyD Aaah yes, I think that will work. Then presumably I could just check up, down, left, and right whenever a card is placed. Thanks, I'll give it a go and credit you in the answer!

Comment: @derHugo That's a good idea, my only hesitation is that with the other proposed solution I wouldn't have to predefine which positions interact with which other positions. I'll see if I can get it to work first. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: "I need to know which slots are adjacent to the one that has just received a card" - If you define a 3x3 grid by setting a Vector2i to indicate a location on the grid, you can simply get the adjacent slots by adding or subtracting from X or Y. Your managing class that knows all card slots could allow each card to address others by slot "coordinate" and you are good to go.